# Create table based on columns from a CSV file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, csv

I have existing code which creates a new table based on the columns of a file (DBF, Excel):

```
OleDbConnection oConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + tbXLSBrowse.Text + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"");

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", oConn); //change to the sheet name

oConn.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

oConn.Close();

DataTableReader reader = dt.CreateDataReader();

myConnection = new SqlConnection(cString);
myConnection.Open();

// checking whether the table selected from the dataset exists in the database or not
string exists = null;
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sysobjects where name = '" + tb.Text + "'", myConnection);
    exists = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    //MessageBox.Show("EXISTS");
}
catch (Exception exce)
{
    exists = null;
    //MessageBox.Show("DOESNT EXIST");
}

if (exists == null)
{
    // selecting each column of the datatable to create a table in the database
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (exists == null)
        {
            SqlCommand createtable = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + tb.Text + " (" + dc.ColumnName + " varchar(MAX))", myConnection);
            createtable.ExecuteNonQuery();
            exists = tbXLSTableName.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand addcolumn = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + tb.Text + " ADD [" + dc.ColumnName + "] varchar(MAX)", myConnection);
            addcolumn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

The textboxes are as follows:

```
//tbXLSBrowse.Text = the excel file name;
//tb.Text = user generated table name;
```

The above code is an example for the Excel file. I have a CSV that I am also trying to do the same for but not sure how to do it.

I have the following code which reads each line in the CSV file and gets the fields for each line and adds it to a List array:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text);
List<string> colArray = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in lines) //for each line
{
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(textBox1.Text))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");

        while (!parser.EndOfData) //while file is being read
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

            foreach (string field in fields) //for each column
            {
                colArray.Add(field);
                colArray.ToArray();
            }

            MessageBox.Show(colArray.Count + ""); //displays the count for the columns for each line
            colArray.Clear(); //clear the column to use it for next line
        }
    }
}
```

How can I combine the code posted in the beginning with the above code to do the following:

- Read the CSV file
- Create a SQL table based on the first row count (which is the header for the file)

Or is it not possible? The reason I am wanting to do this is because there are 329 columns for each line and if I am able to accomplish this with the code, it will save a lot of time in the long run.

Would this site be of any help: [CSV to SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export)

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to expand all the column names in your second code snippet. Once you have read the file in you can use the split command on a string to split the header row into a list (just access the first row of the file using indexing). Then, once you have a list of the column names you can iterate through them using a foreach loop and create the table in the same way you are doing in the above code. Just replace the datacolumn for your string item.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text);
List<string> headerRow = lines.ElementAt(0).Split(',').ToList();
foreach (string header in headerRow)
{
   Create table etc.......
}
```

I hope this helps, the code may not be exactly right but should give you an idea of what you need.

Comment: I get the following error: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'`

Comment: Ok, so you need 'var lines = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text);
            List<string> readHeader = lines.ElementAt(0).Split(',').ToList();'